# How to plot graph while two data (date and X1) append with one list using python

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, time

I have a dataset with date,time and one input column.
Here I wrote the code for input column 7 value by reducing in one hour one hour.(date,value)
Then I put that data into one list. 
After that I want to plot graph according to the value and date of the list. But I can't plot the graph and it display nothing. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
>>> x=[]
>>> some code is running here to decrease the value of 7
>>> x.append({'date':next_record_time, 'X1':new_X1})

>>> print(x)
[{'date': Timestamp('2018-06-08 09:30:00'), 'X1': 7},
 {'date': Timestamp('2018-06-08 10:30:00'), 'X1': 6.5},
 {'date': Timestamp('2018-06-08 11:30:00'), 'X1': 6},
 {'date': Timestamp('2018-06-08 12:30:00'), 'X1': 5.5},
 {'date': Timestamp('2018-06-08 13:30:00'), 'X1': 5}]
```

if we separate it :

```
>>> for i in x:
>>>    print(i['date'], "\t\t", i['X1'])
2018-06-08 09:30:00          7
2018-06-08 10:30:00          6.5
2018-06-08 11:30:00          6
2018-06-08 12:30:00          5.5
2018-06-08 13:30:00          5
2018-06-08 14:30:00          4.5
2018-06-08 15:30:00          4
```

Then I want to plot a graph using this value X1 and date. Then I wrote code and display it without a graph:

```
plt.plot(['date'], ['X1'])
plt.show()
```

graph :
[image]

after adding i into plot :

```
plt.plot(i['date'], i['X1'])
plt.show()
```

got output:

[image]

Comment: You have a typo: you forgot the `i` in front of your indexing. Now you're just trying to plot two lists, each with one sting element. So try `plt.plot(i['data'], i['X1'])`. Additionally, you may want to use some longer/more descriptive variable names

Comment: @Energya thank you for the response. I tried it earlier nothing displayed and in x axis date and y axis values displayed, but not graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(x).plot(x='date', y='X1')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list of dictionaries, you're probably better off creating a dictionary with two lists:

```
>>> my_data = {'dates': [], 'X1': []}
>>> some code is running here to decrease the value of 7
>>> my_data['dates'].append(next_record_time)
>>> my_data['X1'].append(new_X1)

>>> print(my_data)
{'dates': [Timestamp('2018-06-08 09:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 10:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 11:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 12:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 13:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 14:30:00'),
           Timestamp('2018-06-08 15:30:00')],
 'X1': [7, 6.5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4.5, 4]}
```

Then you can make your plot in the way you expected:

```
plt.plot(my_data['dates'], my_data['X1'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: when I apply your code I got this error" unindent does not match any outer indentation level"   for this line "my_data['dates'].append(next_record_time)
"

Comment: As the error says, you should check your indentation levels. I don't have your full code, but I expect you haven't properly (un)indented in a for-loop

Comment: The error is " my_data['dates'].append(next_record_time)
>>> my_data['X1'].append(new_X1)" these two codes I can't write in two lines. I have to write in one line according to my code. So can you tell me how to write it in one line these two codes?

Comment: I don't understand how you cannot add those two lines. You will have to edit your question to show the full code you're working with so I can see